# jQGrid with Oracle db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, oracle, jqgrid-php

I am using jqgrid with oracle database. The fundamental problem is that seemingly everything is correct that not only displays the information in the database table. I leave here all the code that might help me.

book.php

```
<?php
    //database setting
    $dbuser='system';
    $dbpassword='manager';
    $database='orcl';
    $page = 2;
    // get the requested page
    $limit = 10;
    // connect to the database
    $db = oci_connect($dbuser, $dbpassword, $database) or die("Connection Error: " . oci_error());
    $result = oci_parse($db, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from aaz');
    oci_execute($result);

    $row = oci_fetch_array ($result);
    $count = $row[0];
    if( $count > 0 ) 
    {
         $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
    }
    else {
         $total_pages = 0;
    }

    if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
    $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM aaz where rownum <=$limit ORDER BY id";
    $result = oci_parse($db, $SQL) or die("Couldn t execute query.".oci_error());    
    oci_execute($result);

    $responce->page = $page;
    $responce->total = $total_pages;
    $responce->records = $count;
    $i=0;
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($result,OCI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[ID];
        $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[ID],$row[FIRSTNAME],$row[LASTNAME],$row[PHONE],$row[EMAIL]);
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($responce);     
?>
```

index.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>jQGrid example</title>
<!-- Load CSS--><br />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- For this theme, download your own from link above, and place it at css folder -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- Load Javascript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-pt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
<table id="datagrid"></table>
<div id="navGrid"></div>
<p><script language="javascript">
jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid({
    url:'book.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['ID','Nome', 'Apelido', 'Telefone','Email'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'ID',index:'ID', width:155,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
        {name:'FIRSTNAME',index:'FIRSTNAME', width:180,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'LASTNAME',index:'LASTNAME', width:190,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'PHONE',index:'PHONE', width:160, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'EMAIL',index:'EMAIL', width:160, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,15,20,25,30,35,40],
    pager: '#navGrid',
    sortname: 'no',
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: 210,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption:"Example"
});
jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#navGrid',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The answer I get is the book.php:

{"page":2,"total":2,"records":"12","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"3","cell":["3","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"4","cell":["4","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"5","cell":["5","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"6","cell":["6","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"7","cell":["7","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"8","cell":["8","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"9","cell":["9","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]},{"id":"10","cell":["10","fname1","lname1","(000)000-0000","name1@gmail.com"]}]}

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the query for paged data, try changing the query for paging:

```
SELECT * FROM 
     (
       SELECT / * + FIRST_ROWS (n) * / *, ROWNUM rnum FROM (our query) 
 WHERE ROWNUM <= limit-sup
     )
 WHERE rnum > = limit-inf;
```

I hope to help, good luck.